# Javascript - Array undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, undefined, console.log

```
var Items =[
    {name : 'Tv', price : 300},
    {name : 'Phone', price : 200},
    {name : 'album', price : 10},
    {name : 'Candy', price : 2},
    {name : 'T-shirt', price : 100}
];
//forEach Method
Items.forEach(function Item() {
    // body...
    console.log(Items.name);
});
```

But when I run in the console it prints me :
5 undefined.

Comment: You should go read up on how forEach works … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

```
var Items =[
{name : 'Tv', price : 300},
{name : 'Phone', price : 200},
{name : 'album', price : 10},
{name : 'Candy', price : 2},
{name : 'T-shirt', price : 100}
];
 //forEach Method
  Items.forEach(Item=> {
      // body...
       console.log(Item.name);
   });
```

Try this.
or you can use .map method like this

```
Items.map(item=>{
   console.log(item.name);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `Items` is an array, and an array has no property called `name`.  You're trying to access each *element* in the array.  According to [the documentation for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the element is passed to the callback function.  (A function which by the way doesn't need a name, just keep it anonymous.)

For example:

```
Items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item.name);
});
```